# Problem php tage in html Laravel blade showing code on front page

Tags: php, html, laravel

Im trying to link rtl.css in Laravel

style.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/libs/fontawesome/fontawesome.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/libs/toastr/toastr.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/extra/colors.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/extra/extra.css') }}">
@stack('styles_libs')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/application.css') }}">
@stack('styles')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/extra/custom.css') }}">
<?php
if($language->code =="ar") ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/rtl.css') }}">
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

in front.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
@include('frontend.includes.head')
@include('frontend.includes.styles')
</head>
```

---

any help to get the PHP correct in Laravel blade??

the issue is with

```
<?php
if($language->code =="ar") ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/rtl.css') }}">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the URL you're accessing the page with, and what are the exact file names?

Comment: sorry, was a mistake, the names are correct and <!DOCTYPE html> too.

Comment: if your using blade use the @if($language->code =="ar") <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/rtl.css') }}"> @endif instead of <?php .....